# LinkedIn integration Access Denied

Tags: linkedin-api

We have an integration with the LinkedIn API and since yesterday, we have started receiving 403 codes. It is important to note, that we haven't done any changes it just started failing. Is there anything we can do to fix the issue?

The request done is:
[https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/{id}/comments?count=100](https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/%7Bid%7D/comments?count=100)

and the response we're getting is:

```
{
"status": 403,
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: partnerApiSocialActions.GET_ALL.20230801"
}
```

We are expecting as usual a correct response from the API, as mentioned, nothing has been changed in our end it just suddendly started failing

Comment: Have you tried contacting LinkedIn? Normally when these things happen, the owner of the API have made changes to it or the access keys have expired.

Comment: Then I would assume that they will have a dedicated team of talent staff who monitor the `linkedin-api` tagged question and deliver a superior customer service experience from this platform instead of using their own support ticketing system ....pfft!

Comment: Sounds like just another metastasis of this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been polling LinkedIn for an answer, and through other channel I finally got an answer:

> This currently is intended and due to the changes specified here "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions?view=li-lms-2023-11&tabs=http#access-to-social-actions-apis".
> Due to this changes , the call will execute for some version and would not for some LinkedIn version.
> In order to  raise access token for executing "\socialActions" endpoint call irrespective of any version ,  you need to gain access to  community management api which you do not have now for app *"my-app-id"*.
> Currently since there are already other Marketing products added to your developer portal, hence you would not be able to send request for Community Management from same developer app.
> For this please create a new developer app and request for "Community Management" API program  since for requesting access to Community Management, there must not be any other product added to that developer app.
> Once the request is sent, our review team will validate the use case and get back to you since this access request are handled by a different team (Business development team).
> Once you gain access then you can raise a new access token from your developer app with the new permission specified in the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too since today (19th Dec) and reverting to /v2/ appears to have fixed it. I would love to know if there is any way we can monitor these sorts of issues somewhere as trying to deploy an app to production without knowing if something internal is the issue is rather problematic!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something changed but docs didn't updated yet related with permissions. I suggest go back to /v2/socialActions instead of /rest/socialActions